# How to convert a spectrum from spatial frequency to cyc/deg

Tags: matlab, math, signal-processing

I have a hard time wrapping my head around this since there is non-linearity involved. How do I convert a spectrum I have in units "1/m" (or cycles per m) to "cycles/deg"?

**Example**: For simplicity let's work in one dimension and the screen of a laptop is 768 pixels on which I show the highest pixel frequency. I use MATLAB/Octave style code but I hope it's clear enough to act as pseudo code:

```
X = 768
x = 0:X-1
y = cos(2*pi/X*(X/2)*x)
```

The frequency in this signal is now pi radiants or 0.5 cycles/pixel (sampling rate is 1 pixel). I can create the frequency vectors:

```
w = linspace(0, 2*pi, length(x)) % in radiants
f = linspace(0, 1, length(x))    % in 1/pixel or cycles/pixel
```

I can easily convert this to spatial frequency in units [m] and frequency [cycles/m] when I know the pixel size. Let's assume one pixel is 0.5mm:

```
xm = x*0.5e-3 % for image in m
fm = f/0.5e-3 % frequency in 1/m
```

Plotting `y` versus `xm` shows now a waveform with 1 cycle per mm. Plotting the FFT of `y` versus `fm` shows a peak at 1000 cycles/m (or 1 cycle per mm), as expected.

How do I need to modify `fm` to arrive at `fdeg`, in other words, to show the FFT of `y` in cycles per degree, assuming distance from the screen is 60cm? I would assume

```
fdeg = 1/(2*atan(1/fm)/(2*0.6)*180/pi)
```

That would give me 20.97 cycles/deg. However, using the small angle approximation, 1mm should be roughly 1mm/0.6*180/pi=0.9549e-3 degree, so we have 1cycle per 0.9549e-3 degrees or 1/0.9549e-3=10.47 cycles per degree. This is off by a factor of 2.

Comment: 1e-3/0.6*180/pi=0.09549, not 0.9549e-3==0.0009549.

Comment: do you have a deg/m or m/deg number? I've modified the tags because they had no visible relation to your question (no explanation). in fact, that goes for the entire question. introduce it like your reader _can't_ read your mind. "set the stage." perhaps review [ask].